# How to return localtime with javascript date.now()?

Tags: javascript, date

I use date.now() to get a unix timestamp. When I convert this timestamp serverside with PHP the time is always 3 hours earlier. My timezone is `America/Toronto` or `GMT (Eastern Daylight Saving Time)`.

javascript

```
var datetime = Date.now();//1589127005844
```

php

```
//convert unix to datetime
$datetime = '1589127005844';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime/1000);
```

result

```
2020-05-10 09:10:05
```

should be

```
2020-05-10 12:10:05
```

Comment: The timestamp number is always in UTC. You apply the timezone when you format it in PHP: it's the PHP code you should be looking at, not generating the number in JavaScript. e.g. you probably want to call [date-default-timezone-set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in your PHP first.

Comment: This looks like a PHP question not a JavaScript one.

Comment: @Rup: Not a PHP question. I want to do this client-side and I need it to be so.

Comment: @Bergi : I'd like to do it client-side. if I do new Date(), time is in the right timezone. How come I can't get it right with Date.now()?

Comment: @Covid19 `new Date` and `Date.now()` both are in the right time zone (or actually, none at all - they're UTC timestamps). It's your PHP code failing to interpret that and convert it to the desired timezone.

Comment: I'd guess the correct way to do this is to pass the timestamp and timezone from JavaScript to PHP and use both in PHP to render the time as a string. However at first glance I can't see a great way to pass the timezone from one to the other: JavaScript returns the offset by default, and PHP wants the 'America/Toronto' style timezone.

Comment: But Alberto's (now deleted) answer raises a fair point: do you need to format this on the server side? Can you just leave it up to the client to render this time back to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Alright after a few tests. I couldn't find anything truly satisfying to be done client-side. Whatever the case may be it seems I have to do conversion server-side.
I ended up getting timezone client-side and converting [server-side](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Client

```
var start_time = Date.now();
var timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");

var valuescheckk = 'userid=' + encodeURIComponent(userid)
    + '&start_time=' + encodeURIComponent(start_time)
    + '&timezone=' + encodeURIComponent(timezone);

    //send to ajax
    if(valuescheckk !==''){

    $.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: 'time.php',
    data: valuescheckk,
    success: function (data) {

     console.log(data.mytime);

    }

    });

    }
```

time.php

```
if(isset($_POST['start_time'])){
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['userid']);
$start_time= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['start_time']);
$timezone= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['timezone']);

//set timezome
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$startTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_time/1000);

    //return answer to json
           $result = array('message' => 'success',
                       'mytime'=>$startTime
                       );
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($result);
}
```